# Riemann integrable as a convergent series

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum, stieltjes-integral

If $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ show that:
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(k/n)$$

how can I prove this?

Comment: It's true if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: What is your definition of the LHS? Some authors just define it to be the RHS.

Comment: The definition is given by Riemman sums, forany $\varepsilon>0$ exists a partition... such that any selection $x_k^*$, $|S(f,P)-I|<\varepsilon$

Comment: As a hint, I found that: "suppose that $f$ is not integrable and show that a sequence defined as RHS may not converges".

Comment: The right hand side is just a Riemann sum for the left hand side...

Comment: I know, but I have to be more descriptive in the proof, could you give me some hint for the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(x)$ is integrable in $[0,1]$, than for any partition $\{0,t_{1}, t_{2}, ... , t_{n-1}, 1\}$ any for any choose of the element $x_{i}$ from each interval $x_{i} \in [t_{i},t_{i+1}]$, the Riemann sum defined $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_{i})(t_{i+1}-t_{i})$ converges to the quantity denoted $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ which in unique. So you can choose arbitrary the partition and the element of each interval.

Now note that for your case the partition is $\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}, ... , \frac{n-1}{n}, 1\}$ and choosen elements are exactly the left bounds of that intervals.

So this is in some sense particural case (for the definition).

The only thing i'm stuck with whether the sum should go form 0 to n, or to n-1 (or maybe form 1 to n).